# Algabra.js solveFor returns an empty array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the following equation:
**‌125/36 = -p^2 + 2p**

however, I get empty array.

code to replicate:

```
let leftSide = new Expression(125).divide(36);
let rightSide = algebra.parse("-p^2 + 2p");
let equation = new Equation(leftSide, rightSide);
let solvedAnswers = equation.solveFor("p");
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminant of the equation: `125/36 = -p^2 + 2p` is negative. That means it has complex roots. I haven't worked with algebra.js but it might not return any values if there are no real roots.

Read: http://www.mathwords.com/d/discriminant_quadratic.htm